# How to configure Teamcity git plugin to init submodules NON-recursively

Tags: git, teamcity, git-submodules

According to its repo git-plugin has such functionality (http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=teamcity/git-plugin.git;a=commit;h=b2354dbef90b793d7e24c6f3c135f7a0bec4ad15)
I'm wondering is there a way to disable recursive submodules (fetch only first-level submodules) via Teamcity web UI? Or is there any other way to workaround this cause I need it for my current project.

*This question is mirrored in http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5500243

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this functionality is missing for current Gaya 8.0.4 release of Teamcity, so I filed a feature-request for it http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-32570